# Upload locally developed AWS Glue pyspark notebook

Tags: pyspark, aws-glue

AWS [touts](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2022/01/aws-glue-interactive-sessions-job-notebooks/) developers can develop notebooks in the IDE of their choice. While I was able to get a downloaded notebook running in VS Code using the Glue PySpark kernel, I do not see how I can now upload the changes made locally to the Glue Job.

Does anyone have any experience with that?

Comment: I may have understood now that you would just use the notebook locally, generate the python script and upload that as a job. The "Jupyter Notebook" option is really only for developing in Glue Studio. Maybe someone could confirm my understanding.

Comment: Never tried that before, but you can try first loading the notebook on S3 and then call the glue.Code.from_bucket() function as described here => https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v1/python/aws_cdk.aws_glue/Code.html

This code uses the aws CDK, so you gotta install that first

Comment: Not sure it will work, I never tried this, plus you're right, the notebook on Glue is thought to be used on your browser to test and debug functions, so I don't really think there's a way to directly upload a notebook, but it's worth trying

Comment: Thanks @GiuseppeCannizzaro. I may pursue your suggestion at a later point when we build up a ci/cd process. For now, I am going with copy and pasting the generated python script.